# How to do something with component in controller (Swing)?

Tags: java, swing, view, controller, components

I create a simple view with two methods, first method put all components on panel into hashmap, and second get component with hashmap by name:

```
public class AddMaker extends JFrame {

private static HashMap componentMap;

//first
private void createComponentMap(JPanel jPanel) {
    componentMap = new HashMap<String,Component>();
    Component[] components = jPanel.getComponents();
    for (int i=0; i < components.length; i++) {
        componentMap.put(i, components[i].getName());
    }
}

//second
public static Component getComponentByName(String name) {
    if (componentMap.containsValue(name)) {
        System.out.println("name  " + name );
        return (Component) componentMap.get(name);
    }
    else return null;
}


private JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();

//labels
private JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel("Add");

public AddMaker(){
    setSize(400, 300);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    //set panel layout
    jPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    //do some align
    jLabel1.setName("namee");
    jLabel1.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    jPanel.add(jLabel1);

    //creating hashmap with components on panel
    createComponentMap(jPanel);

    //add panel on form
    getContentPane().add(jPanel);
}
```

In my controller, I want to get some component and do something with him:

```
public class AddMakerController {

public JFrame addMaker = new AddMaker();

public AddMakerController(){
    JLabel jLabel = (JLabel) AddMaker.getComponentByName("namee");
    addMaker.setVisible(false);
}
}
```

But when form is opening, the appear this error, anybody have an idea?

```
name  namee
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at mvc.controller.AddMakerController.<init>(AddMakerController.java:18)
at mvc.controller.CountryController$1.actionPerformed(CountryController.java:300)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
...
```

**Edit:**
I handle this exception, my code in controller:

```
public class AddMakerController {

public AddMaker addMaker = new AddMaker();

public AddMakerController(){
    Component component = addMaker.getComponentByName("namee");
    if (component instanceof JLabel) {
        JLabel jLabel = (JLabel) component;
        jLabel.setText("l");
        addMaker  =new AddMaker(); //not edit label on form..
    }
}
}
```

Now, I want to change the text in label, how to show result of this operations in controller?

Thanks.

Comment: As per your error stack trace, the error is on line number 18, please post your code which generating the error.

Comment: If you want to change text of label then use setText(String) method. And if I guess correctly you want to change the text of label while processing, if it is then follow this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html